# jquery UI syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code on my page that seems to work fine in Chrome, but not any other browser. Did I miss-key something? http://jsfiddle.net/fg823c3y/

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    $( "#container" ).draggable(
    { 
        handle: "#handle", 
        containment: "body", 
        scroll: false 
    });

    $('head').append('<style type="text/css">#handle:hover{cursor: move;}</style>');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: any errors in browser console on firefox?

Comment: no.... not seeing any errors

Comment: Make a fiddle or insert snippet here

Comment: i'm seeing TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$( "#container" )')

Comment: added fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fg823c3y/

Comment: works for me in firefox.  i can drag the div.

Comment: What exactly did you mean by *"work fine"*? for me it doesn't work *fine* in chrome, safari and opera. i can drag the `<div>` even outside body. works *fine* in FF.

Answer (score -1):

Working fine on Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/me18qges/

It was just dragging sideways, but adding a few line breaks solved this.

I don't see why the `setTimeout`, just declare it on your [ready function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Also don't see why the css insertion, just add it to your global css.

From your comment: `undefined is not a function` when calling `$("something")` means jQuery is not declared, check your jQuery js declaration.